# How can I access messages in a JavaScript template in Play! Framework?

Tags: java, javascript, html, templates, playframework

I have a template `public/js/templates/info.html`:

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="button">&{'info.close'}</div>
    <div class="info-title"><%= title %></div>
    <div class="info-text"><%= description %></div>
</div>
```

`&{'info.close'}` should print the "Close Info" text from messages - but in web page I see "&{'info.close'}".

This work perfectly in a html view, but it doesn't work for templates. I am using JavaScript templates as that comes with backbone.js/underscore.js.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [i18n tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/tags#i18n)

Comment: i've tried that, and that works fine in js file, but the tmpl is a html fragment stored in a html file.

Comment: if it is loaded by javascript itself then you should try <%=i18n('info.close')%> everything inside those tags should be processed as javascript

Answer (score 1):

Resources in the public directory are considered static data items. They are not processed by Play through the templating engine, but instead just served up as is.

If you want to make use of dynamic data, which includes internationalised javscript files, you have a couple of options.

1. Load the internationalised message data as JSON response from within your javascript
2. Define the templates inside your view, rather than in a separate file
3. Load the file via controller action as if it were any other view

Your specific requirements will determine which is the right approach for your application.